# Spring - Retrieve all scanned packages

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a Spring Starter project and need to get all classes which are marked with a custom annotation. The annotated class is not a spring bean.

My current solution is to use the ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider to find the required classes.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
            new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(CustomAnnotation.class));
    candidates = scanner.findCandidateComponents("THE MISSING PACKAGE NAME");
```

The problem is that I'm currently provide an empty package String so that all packages/classes are scanned which slows the startup down.

I need to access the packages which are scanned by Spring to avoid the scanning of all packages and classes.

Is there a way to retrieve all packages programmatically which are scanned by Spring or is there an alternative solution to retrieve custom annotated classes which are not Spring beans.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

One solution without the need to make a full classpath scan is to use the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:

```
private List<Class<?>> candidates = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInstantiation(Class<?> beanClass, String beanName) throws BeansException {
  if(beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(YourAnnotation.class)){
        candiates.add(beanClass));
        System.out.println(beanClass);
        return new Object();
    }
}

@Bean
public CandiateHolder candidates() {
    return new CandidateHolder(candidates);
}
```

You can check if the bean class which should be instantiated has the required annotation. If its the case you add the class to a property to expose it later as a bean. Instead of returning null you have to return an instance of a new Object. The returned object can be used to wrap the class in a proxy. Cause I don't need an instance I will return a simple new object. Its maybe a dirty hack but it works.

I have to use this kind of hack cause an instantiation of the needed object will result in an runtime error cause it has to be instantiated in the framework I use.